# Generating combination of arrays from JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this below response

Response

```
const result = [
  {
    Id: "1",
    Char1: "a; b; c",
    Char2: "d; e; f"
  }
];
```

Currently I am generating output like below from my below JS code

```
Id,Char1,Char2
1,a,d
1,b,e
1,c,f
```

But I want to generate output like below with all combination of Char1 and Char2 with rest of the data-

```
Id,Char1,Char2
1,a,d
1,a,e
1,a,f
1,b,d
1,b,e
1,c,f
1,c,d
1,c,e
1,c,f
```

JS -

```
result
    .reduce((acc, {
        Id,
        Char1,
        Char2
    }) => {
        const a = Char1.split(";");
        const c = Char2.split(";");
        a.forEach((item, index) => {
            acc.push({
                Id: Id,
                Char1: item,
                Char2: c[index]
            });
        });
        return acc;
    }, [])
    .forEach(item => {
        lines.push(rowData.map(key => item[key]).join(","));
    });
```

Comment: Yes.. i saw that. But i need to have the Id value in each row.. how to get that..

Comment: after you have an array with all combinatins map it and add id to each element. Hold on I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For every item in `Char1`'s split array, you need to loop over every item in `Char2`'s split array. So, you can use an inner `.forEach` loop within your `a.forEach` to loop over `Char2`'s values like so:

```js
const result = [{
  Id: "1",
  Char1: "a; b; c",
  Char2: "d; e; f"
}];

const combs = result.reduce((acc, {Id, Char1, Char2}) => {
  const a = Char1.split(";");
  const c = Char2.split(";");
  a.forEach((aitem) => {
    c.forEach((citem) => {
      acc.push({Id, char1: aitem.trim(), char2: citem.trim()});
    })
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

const ppres = Object.keys(result[0]) + combs.reduce((a, o) => a +Object.values(o) +'\n', '\n');
console.log(ppres);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using two forEach

```
result
    .reduce((acc, {
        Id,
        Char1,
        Char2
    }) => {
        const a = Char1.split(";");
        const c = Char2.split(";");
        a.forEach((item, index) => {

          c.forEach((item1,index1)=>{
              acc.push({
                Id: Id,
                Char1: item,
                Char2: item1
            });

          })

        });
        return acc;
    }, [])
    .forEach(item => {
        lines.push(rowData.map(key => item[key]).join(","));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Getting this from your api response you can do
const Id = "1";
const Char1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const Char2 = ["d", "e", "f"];

const combo = [];  // To hold the final array

Char1.forEach(function(a1){
  Char2.forEach(function(a2){
    combo.push(`${Id}, ${a1}, ${a2}`);  // Two loops to get all combinations, put same id in every string.
  });
});

console.log(combo);
```